# PHP Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server inside docker

Tags: php, ldap

My problem is that I want to connect to ldap server and take out some information. When I use a simple script on my local computer like this

```
$connection = ldap_connect('ldap://ad.organization.ru:389');
ldap_set_option($connection, 17, 3);
ldap_set_option($connection, 8, false);
$res = ldap_bind($connection, 'cn=admin,cn=users,dc=ad,dc=organization,dc=ru', 'password');
```

everything works correctly. If I try to connect to server via console command, everything works too:

```
ldapsearch -x -LLL -h ad.organization.ru -D 'cn=admin,cn=users,dc=ad,dc=organization,dc=ru' -w password -b 'cn=Users,dc=ad,dc=organization,dc=ru' -s sub '(sAMAccountName=user)'
```

But if I try to the same thing inside docker container I see this error:

> *PHP Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server*

Docker and php on my local computer have the same versions(php 7.3.14 and php 7.3.16)

The only difference is Vendor version of ldap extension.

System - ubuntu 18.04.

Also, I shoud add that I connect to this ldap server via vpn.

Does anybody knows the reason of such strange behaviour?

Comment: Is your docker-container using the VPN connection?

Comment: @heiglandreas I think yes. I mean that my computer works using vpn.( so docker uses it too)

Comment: What does a VPN do that would cause an issue? I’m having the same problem...

Comment: Honestly, don't remember, now I have no problems with it.